# jQuery add css class depending on selectbox option

Tags: jquery, css, class, element, drop-down-menu

I have 3 dropdown where I want to add a class to a specific div depending on the value of the dropdown.

```
<select name="item1">
    <option>Blue</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Red</option>
</select>

<select name="item2">
    <option>Blue</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Red</option>
</select>

<select name="item3">
    <option>Blue</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Red</option>
</select>

<div class="product">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <div class="item2"></div>
    <div class="item3"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to add a css class depending on the value of a dropdown.
For example, if the option **blue** from the dropdown **item1** is selected, I would like to add a class **.blue** to the div **item1**.

I used to have checkboxes instead of the dropdown and I had this code:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('input#red').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('div.item1').addClass("red");
        } else {
            $('div.item1').removeClass("red");
        }
    });
    $('input#blue').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('div.item1').addClass("blue");
        } else {
            $('div.item1').removeClass("blue");
        }
    });
});
```

I created this: http://jsfiddle.net/uJcB7/14/
How does should be done correctly?

------------EDIT-----------

I am using gravity forms to generate the select box, and they are adding "|0" after the name of the option (I don't know why!).

For example "green|0" instead of "green". The "|0" is hidden in the field but the class generated is "green|0".

Any thought on how to remove that "|0" on the css class?

Also they generate a name for the selectbox, is it possible to use a class instead of using the name element?

Have a look on the updated code:

http://jsfiddle.net/uJcB7/24/

Answer (score 2):

The class of the `<div>` to add the class to is the same as the `name` property of the `<select>` element being changed, and the name of the class to add is the lower case version of the value of the option selected. With that in mind, this works:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('select').change(function(){
        $('.' + this.name).attr('class', this.name + ' ' + this.value.toLowerCase());
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uJcB7/20/)

Comment: Short and sweet. Nice! I would only warn the OP that this will act on *any* select element, so they may need to filter it in some way, like Roko suggested.

Comment: It also hardcodes the class names to remove, so OP will need to remember to update this function if the values of the select menus change

Comment: @jackwanders I couldn't decide on the best method to handle that, but have now. I've edited the code so that, rather than adding/removing specific classes, it simply overwrites the class attribute with the required new classes - that will be *itemX* and *red/blue/green*.

Comment: that's what i had in my first solution; basically resetting the class. However, if the div looks like `<div class="item 1 rounded-corners">`, then you lose the `rounded-corners` class. that's why I settled on using $.map to get all option values

Comment: @jackwanders Assuming the HTML in use actually looks like the HTML in the question, that wouldn't be an issue in this specific case. In general, however, you're correct; `$.map()` would be the more generic solution.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist thank you very much for your answer! This is the first time I usedstackoverflow and I am well impressed! Thank you for your time and the excellence of your solution!

Comment: @AnthonyGrist is there a quick way to update the code to allow a space in between two words? For example I have a colour named 'light blue' can we transform a space by a - for the css class? (.light-blue)

Comment: @user1482757 You can add `.replace(/\s+/,'-')` after the `this.value.toLowerCase()` to replace any amount of whitespace with a dash (-). [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJcB7/21/).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I am using gravity forms to generate the select box, and they are adding |0 after the name of the option. For exemple "green|0" instead of "green". The "|0" is hidden in the field but the class generated is "green|0". Any thought on how to remove that "|0" on the css class? Also they generate a name for the selectbox, is it possible to use a class instead of using the name element? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general function that will add the text value of the selected option to the appropriate div:

```
$(document).ready(function($){

  $('select').change(function(){
    var s = $(this);
    var name = s.attr('name');
     $('.'+name).removeClass().addClass(name+' '+s.find(':selected').text().toLowerCase());
  });
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/xcEa9/4/

Even more generally, you can use $.map to obtain a list of the select menu's values so that you know which class names to remove on each change event:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var values = $.map($this.find('option'),function(opt){ return opt.value.toLowerCase(); }).join(' ');
    $('.'+this.name).removeClass(values).addClass($(this).val().toLowerCase());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/xcEa9/5/

Comment: That's an unnecessary amount of jQuery to access properties that are readily available via `this` (the `<select>` element that triggered the event).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#item1').change(function() {
    $('.item1').addClass($('#item1').val());
  });

  $('#item2').change(function() {
    $('.item2').addClass($('#item2').val());
  });

  $('#item3').change(function() {
    $('.item3').addClass($('#item3').val());
  });

});
```

You can also keep the individual segments within for loop if you like.

Answer (score 0):

This one will work for all your `select` elements.

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/ZnFjq/2/)*

```
$('select[name^=item]').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('div.'+$(this).attr('name')).removeClass('red blue green').addClass(val);
});
```

`select[name^=item]` Searches for a select element which name starts with `item`

Comment: Since you're not removing the other classes, this doesn't work if you select `green` and then switch the value back to `red` or `blue` because the `.green` CSS declaration takes precedence over the others. Also, as with jackwanders answer, considerably more jQuery than required.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $('select').bind('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('option:not(:selected)').each(function(index, option) {
      $this.removeClass($(option).text());
    });
    $this.addClass($this.find('option:selected').text());
  });        
});
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJcB7/17/)

Answer (score 0):

This clears the previously set color value in the class (if any) and sets the new one.

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('select').change(function(){
        name = $(this).attr('name');
        curClass = $('div.'+name).attr('class');
        $('div.'+name).removeClass(curClass).addClass(name + ' ' +$(this).val());
    });
});
```

​
**[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/supermykel/Cq7LY/)**